# printing maximum number of consecutive 1's in python

Tags: python

Im trying to print the maximum number of consecutive 1's in python...but im getting stuck here....IDK why im getting a syntax error...strange...can anyone help me out

```
li2 = []
t = int(input())
for i in range(0, t):    //testcases
    n = int(input())
    for i in range(n):    //length of list(binary array)
        li = list(map(int, input().strip().split())
        count = 0
        max_count=0
        for i in range(len(li)):
            if (li[i] == 0):
                count = 0
            else:
                count += 1
                max_count = max(max_count,count)  
        li2.append(max_count)
                  
            
for i in range(len(li2)):
    print(li2[i])
```

```
File "<ipython-input-2-f159cb61e247>", line 7
    count = 0
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: First comment should be defined by `#` not by `//` in python

Comment: Bracket is not closed. `list(map(int, input().strip().split()))`

Comment: ohh sorry i just edited that now...for people to know why is that loop created

Comment: @Pygirl Thanks a lotttt

Comment: BTW logic seems to be wrong to me.

Comment: yeah Im trying still

Comment: This is `for i in range(n):` <--- unnecessary. If you are coding in hackerrank. Then there is no need of that. They always provide you numbers with that length only you can write try except for the length when to avoid that example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improve the above answer using inline function

```py
li2 = []
t = int(input())
for i in range(0, t):    #testcases
    n = int(input())
    li = ''.join(input().split())
    li = [n if n == '1' else '0' for n in li]   # replace the numbers not '1' to '0'
    max_count = max(map(len, ''.join(li).split('0')))  # split by '0' and get max length from each 1's
    li2.append(max_count)
print() 
for i in range(len(li2)):
    print(li2[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

**Corrections:**

```
li2 = []
t = int(input())
for i in range(0, t):    #testcases
    n = int(input())
    li = list(map(int, input().strip().split())) #<--- before that loop is removed.
    count = 0
    max_count=0
    for i in range(len(li)):
        if (li[i] != 1):  #<------- Here
            count = 0
        else:
            count += 1
        max_count = max(max_count,count)  #<--- here
    li2.append(max_count)
print() 
for i in range(len(li2)):
    print(li2[i])
```

---

```
3
5
2 1 1 1 1
3 
2 3 4
7
1 2 3 1 1 1 1

4
0
4
```

Comment: YEPP it works Thanks.....but why was that FOR loop be removed??

Comment: `list(map(int, input().strip().split()))` You have used this right? You are giving input like this: `2 1 1 1 1` at once only that's why

Comment: oohh okay..got it